# .replace() not working for escaping back slashes in JavaScript for Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, json, schema, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to dynamically populate schema into my company's blog posts. Most things work just fine, but URLs, for some reason, have escape characters behind each /. Examples are denoted by '**' below in the schema markup

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "BlogPosting",
  "headline": "HHHunts Commitment To RVA",
  "image": "",  
  "author": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "HHHunt"
    "url": "https://hhhunt.com"
  },  
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "HHHunt",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      **"url": "https:\/\/assets-global.website-files.com\/61d6f3d648b8c96670b238ab\/61d86f26213077625ab3a90e_logo-130.png"**
    }
  },
  "datePublished": "2022-03-28",
  "articleBody": "When ... ‍", // shortened
  **"thumbnailUrl": "https:\/\/assets-global.website-files.com\/61d6f3d648b8c989b9b238c0\/624311d33025d92e76fb34b9_Habitat-for-Humaity-(2).jpg",**
  "timeRequired": "PT3M",
  "description": "Growing up in Richmond, VA, Harry H. Hunt, III has always held a special place in heart for RVA and made a commitment to supporting and investing in the region.",
}
</script>
```

My code for replacing the escape characters is:

```
function() {
  var postUrl = document.getElementsByClassName('schema-blog-image')[0].innerText;
  var cleanPostUrl = postUrl.replace(/[\\]/g,"")
  return cleanPostUrl;
}
```

where .schema-blog-image is the class selector for the blog's featured image.

In the above 'url' fields, I was able to get the URL in no problem using Google Tag Manager's JavaScript variable to get the image source from the HTML using the same class name. However, when I tried to use the function above using the same class name but for "image," it returns an empty string (as seen above).

Some Googling led me to try `return JSON.stringify(postUrl)` (while removing the cleanPostUrl var), but that just gives me `\x22\x22` as a result.

The function above worked perfectly when I tried it on the [`W3 Schools Try It Yourself`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace2) editor, so I'm not sure what else to do to make the regex work.

None of this replaced the escape characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got this figured out by following a guide I found on [Moz.com](https://moz.com/blog/using-google-tag-manager-to-dynamically-generate-schema-org-json-ld-tags)

Here's what the tag code looks like now:

```html
<script>
  (function(){
    var data = {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "BlogPosting",
      "headline": {{Post Title}},
      "image": {{Post Image}},
      "author": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "HHHunt",
        "url": "https://hhhunt.com"
      },  
      "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "HHHunt",
        "logo": {
          "@type": "ImageObject",
          "url": {{Logo}}
        },
      },
      "datePublished": {{ISO Date}},
      "articleBody": {{Post Content}},
      "thumbnailUrl": {{Post Image}},
      "timeRequired": "PT" + {{Duration}} + "M", // I had to adjust this line to allow a string concat using a variable
      "description": {{Meta Description}},
    }
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "application/ld+json";
    script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data); 
    document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].appendChild(script); // write the script to my <footer> tag
  })(document);
</script>
```

My variables are just the raw element attributes (e.g. the image is gotten from using a DOM Element variable, targeting the CSS Selector I provided, and using the src attribute to get the URL). The difference now is that my schema is now wrapped inside a variable inside a function, where I can now pass all these variables through as true strings. From there, we can create a var script and use that to create a new script HTML element with the properties I need and insert it where I need it.

Since I was able to use these variables as true strings within the variable 'data' itself, I no longer need to worry about escaping characters.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var cleanPostUrl= JSON.stringify(postUrl);
var data = JSON.parse(cleanPostUrl);
```

Comment: `function() {
  var postUrl = document.getElementsByClassName('schema-blog-image')[0].innerText;
  var cleanPostUrl= JSON.stringify(postUrl);
  var data = JSON.parse(cleanPostUrl);
  return data;
}`
returns an empty string

Comment: @NickVogel the code was tested using json you posted. If it is null now it means that postUrl is null and json is null.

Comment: the empty string was because I used `.innerText` instead of `.src`, so I now see the URL. Using what you sent, I still see it in the code as `"image": "https:\/\/assets-global.website-files.com\/61d6f3d648b8c989b9b238c0\/624311d33025d92e76fb34b9_Habitat-for-Humaity-(2).jpg"` and in Google Tag Manager as `"image": "https:\\/\\/assets-global.website-files.com\\/61d6f3d648b8c989b9b238c0\\/624311d33025d92e76fb34b9_Habitat-for-Humaity-(2).jpg"`

 I am able to replace the `\\/` using the regex I used before, but I now can't replace it using "/" or "\/" in the replace function.